# Couette Flow encountering an airfoil obstruction

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, bernoulli-equation

Im interested in what would happen to an airfoil place within a Couette type fluid flow bounded between a fixed and moving boundary plate

[image]

If we say the plate is infinite to establish a steady state what would that steady state be?

Would a Bernoulli type pressure variation be established as there is a fluid flow relative to stationary airfoil

Since there is no pressure gradient in the direction of the flow im struggling to see how that could happen but also cant identify what would occur.

Comment: It is going to depend on how far the airfoil is from the plates and the Reynolds number based on airfoil dimensions.  Imagine the situation if the plates were 5 miles apart, the airfoil is half-way between, and the airfoil is only 1" in maximum thickness.

Comment: @ChesterMiller yes good point . i guess i was framing the question of momentum presented to the obstruction. If it was too dy was too large I imagine that no momentum would be present near the airfoil. Is it simpler to say in a scenario where a non-trivial amount of momentum encounters the airfoil ?